# What measures to take in Scotland on unclear 2-day PCR test

Tags: scotland, covid-19

A colleague took a 2-day PCR test as required when travelling to Scotland from abroad. The test resolved to unclear and informed that a new test is needed.

I cannot find information on what measure to take, it seems they do not need to isolate, but there is seemingly no working phone number to call when you have an abroad phone number ("we have identified you are not calling from Scotland and will disconnect you").

Can we order a new test on mail and wait, or do we need to find a in-site tester right away to not need to isolate?

Do they need to isolate, it is not clear.

They are fully vaccinated and have no symptoms.

Comment: I'd say keep isolating, just in case. But I am no medic.

Comment: I can’t find the equivalent page for NHS Scotland, however the rules set out here https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/testing/test-results/test-sample-could-not-be-read-void/ are pretty much valid UK-wide AFAIK. You need to take another test but **only** need to self isolate if the circumstances listed apply to you (which it seems they currently do not).

Answer (score 7):

**Official answer from NHS:** "need to get a new PCR-test as soon as possible"

**Half-formal answer when mentioning that a second PCR-test would not conclude until after leaving the country:** "get a couple of LFD-tests to be on the safe side"

**Action solution:** The lab reprocessed the original PCR-test later that day with a negative result and apologised for the confusion